# Convert date from mm/yyyy to mm/yy using either date-fns or moment

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-format, date-fns

I have a string representing a expiry date coming through in format mm/yyyy ie `01/2021` representing January 2021.

Would it possible to convert the date string `mm/yy` using either date-fns or moment?

I can't access `date-fns` documentation as their site appears to be not responding.

I have attempted:

```
const myDate = '01/2021';

const dateFns = format(myDate, 'MM/YY');

const mom = moment(myDate).format('MM/YY');
```

however I'm not having any luck.

Would it be required for me to add some bogus date to the start of the string in order for these to work correctly?

Comment: The date-fns site is working for me.

Comment: "I'm not having any luck." be specific about the errors/what's not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation using moment.js

```
import Moment from "moment";

let datestring = "08/2021";
let date = Moment(datestring, "MMYYYY");
let datedot = date.format("MMMM YYYY");
alert(datedot); // Output - August 2021
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kgrhff?file=index.ts